# How to stop the route when the processing of files is done?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I working spring application and my rest endpoint will convert the .csv into .text and .sem files.

I am able to do by creating a camel context and addRoutes to it but I am using Thread.sleep(miliseconds) is there any to avoid the thread sleep and stop when the processing is done.

```
getCamelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){
       public void configure(){
             File folder = new File(filePath);
             File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
             for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
              {
        if (listOfFile.isFile() && listOfFile.getName().contains(".csv")) {
              from("file:" + fromRoute + listOfFile.getName()).to("file:" + 
              toArchiveRoute + csvArchive).unmarshal(bindy).to("file:" + 
              toTextRoute + txtFileName + ".txt").to("file:" + duplicateTextRoute + txtFileName + ".txt
                      }
          });

getCamelContext.start();
Thread.sleep(5000);
getCamelContext.stop();}
```

Is there any thing that I can get rid it of Thread.sleep(miliseconds) I tired reading apache camel in action shutdown the routes but I am unable to achieve the result.

Answer (score -1):

You might be searching for [Graceful Shutdown](http://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html).
Using `DefaultShutdownStrategy` should be enough in your case.

Some functions depend on your camel version, like the individual shutdown of routes.

Examples with code can be found [here](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/graceful-shutdown.html).

```
getCamelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){
       public void configure(){
             File folder = new File(filePath);
             File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
             for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
              {
        if (listOfFile.isFile() && listOfFile.getName().contains(".csv")) {
              from("file:" + fromRoute + listOfFile.getName())
              .to("file:" + toArchiveRoute + csvArchive)
              .unmarshal(bindy)
              .shutdownRoute(Defer) //Add this here
              .to("file:" + toTextRoute + txtFileName + ".txt")
              .to("file:" + duplicateTextRoute + txtFileName + ".txt
                      }
          });
```

I cannot test this right now, but I am pretty sure you must use `Defer` as strategy, because you are reading the files from an array.